# how can i make join query in parse android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created 5 tables in parse.com for my Android App:
  1. `users` (name, password,phone, etc)
  2. `list` (List-name ,Note, Image,user)
  3. `subscribe_user_list` (list, user)
  4. `favorite_user_list` (list, user)
  5. `contacts` (contact_name, number, list)

Every `list` has multiple `contacts`. A user can subscribe to a list and can mark a list as favorite. 
I want to get all lists from `list` table to which user has subscribed with following details for every list:
1. Total count of users who have subscribed to the list
2. Total number of users who have marked the list as favorite
3. Total number of contact in that list.

This is easily possible in SQL using multiple join queries, however, I don't know how to get this in a single query in parse. Is there anyone who can help me in this..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [compound queries](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-compound) to create queries based on other queries results.

Comment: I have tried it but it make my app  slow and progress bar get stuck.Is there not any way to short it out..Like in MySQL  we can make a single query for this..

Answer (score 0):

```
   "you must create a separate table in which the relationship is tracked. 
   This table, which we will call Favourite, would have a 'User_Id'
   column and a 'Favourite_Id' column, each with a pointer to a Parse User."



    currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Favourite");
    query.whereEqualTo("User_Id", currentUser);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objectList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                userList = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
                parseUsers = new ArrayList<ParseUser>();
                for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
                    userList.add((ParseObject) objectList.get(i).get("Favourite_Id"));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
                    userList.get(i).fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                parseUsers.add(object);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


            }

        }
    });
```